# Count the occurrences of strings in PHP a second time

Tags: php

I have a list of events, which contains keywords entered by the user. At the end of each day I aggregate all of them and count the occurrences of each keyword (note that I count NULL as well) with the following code:

```
$nameArray = [];
foreach ($eventsYesterday as $event) {
   if (empty($event->name)) {
       $nameNullCounter++;
   } else {
       array_push($nameArray, strtolower($event->name));
   }
}
$countedNameArray = array_count_values($nameArray);
```

At this point I have a result set that contains the count for each keyword.

I then save them to my aggregation table every night (just after midnight) as so:

```
//If there has been more than 0 NULL searches on name, insert that too with its counter
            if ($nameNullCounter > 0) {
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $obj->name = NULL;
                $obj->amount_name = $nameNullCounter;
                $obj->region_name = $regionName;
                $time = strtotime("-1 day", time());
                $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", $time);
                $obj->timestamp = $yesterday;      //Since this is executed after midnight, we need to insert the date of yesterday
                $this->searchOrganisationNameLocAggr_model->add($obj);
            }
            //Insert for each occurence in the searchOrganisationNameLocAggr model
            foreach ($countedNameArray as $key => $value) {
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $obj->name = $key;
                $obj->amount_name = $value;
                $obj->region_name = $regionName;
                $time = strtotime("-1 day", time());
                $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", $time);
                $obj->timestamp = $yesterday;      //Since this is executed after midnight, we need to insert the date of yesterday
                $this->searchOrganisationNameLocAggr_model->add($obj);
            }
```

When my users view statistics, I give them the option to select a date range. So if for example they choose "last week", they will get the data from yesterday until yesterday - 7 days.

For this I will retrieve the data in my aggregation tabel where the timestamp is between this date range. And I am returned with all the rows together with their amounts of occurrences (PER DAY).

Now it is obvious that a keyword that has been searched on 5 times yesterday can also be searched on twice 3 days ago. I would want to "re-count" all these keyword names and add their total amounts up to each other.

An example would be, with the data as so:

```
name: NULL
amount_name: 3
date: 2019-03-13 00:00:00

name: "test"
amount_name: 1
date: 2019-03-13 00:00:00

name: NULL
amount_name: 3
date: 2019-03-14 00:00:00

name: "test"
amount_name: 5
date: 2019-03-14 00:00:00

name: "a"
amount_name: 3
date: 2019-03-14 00:00:00
```

I would want the result to be:

```
name: NULL
amount_name: 6

name: "test"
amount_name: 6

name: "a"
amount_name: 3
```

Comment: are you using sql as database?

Comment: @lessan Yes ! MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query on your mysql:

```
SELECT SUM(amount_name) FROM table WHERE date between(start_date, end_date) GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Omg I totally zoned out of the MySQL solution part, works perfect and it's much simpeler! Thanks a lot!

Comment: usually, it's better when you want to retreive data from a database to process it there. Most of the time it's cleaner and a performance booster

Answer (score 1):

In php

```
$total = array()

foreach($results as $result){
   if (!isset($total[$result->name]) $total[$result->name] = 0
   $total[$result->name]+=$result->amount_name
}
```

but indeed, the mySql solution is better

Comment: Thank you for the insights on how to do this in PHP !